# Docker is not building a text file as output and not able to search the file

Tags: python, docker

I have a python script which is creating a text file. when I run the python script alone it is working fine.

```
class TXT_file():
### initialize the txt_file class
def __init__(self, path2file):
    self.path2file = path2file     
    with open(path2file, "w") as f: 
        f.write("") 

### write sentence to the txt_file
def sentence_to_file(self, sentence):
    with open(self.path2file, "w") as f: 
        f.write(sentence) 

### function initiating the class file and writing "Hello world!"
def run_sequence(path2data, file):
    ### initialize the gps_file class
    my_txt_file = TXT_file(path2data + file)
    my_txt_file.sentence_to_file("Hello world!")

### main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ### setting up paths to various data files
    path2data = 'C:\\Users\\abc\\folder\\'
    file = "example_text_file.txt"
    run_sequence(path2data, file)
```

When I am building a docker image with it. I have installed a Docker for windows and using windows containers. Dockerfile is looking like

```
FROM python:3
ADD txt_file_creation.py /
CMD [ "python", "./txt_file_creation.py", " ./example_text_file.txt"]
```

I am not able to get the file `example_text_file.txt` as output and it throws an error:

I am using following commands to build and run the docker image:

```
docker build -t test_print_1 .
docker run test_print_1
```

the error which I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./txt_file_creation.py", line 34, in <module>
    run_sequence(path2data, file)
  File "./txt_file_creation.py", line 26, in run_sequence
    my_txt_file = TXT_file(path2data + file)
  File "./txt_file_creation.py", line 15, in __init__
    with open(path2file, "w") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\abc\\folder\\example_text_file.txt'
```

How can I print the file in the same folder with docker.

Comment: If you get an interactive shell in the image (`docker run --rm -it test_print_1 bash`) and look around, what do you see?  Which files are and aren't there?

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: container bfbdc595a70b8de7f4e27215234778ea58bfe6695c3ca7bc7c97096788540826 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"bash","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"PYTHON_PIP_VERSION":"18.1","PYTHON_RELEASE":"3.7.2","PYTHON_VERSION":"3.7.2"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[30,120]}.

Comment: If `docker run ... bash` doesn't work then `sh` probably will (without, for example, interactive shell history).

Comment: so I ran , docker run -it test_print_1 sh and it gave me following:

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: container acf6a6dd1243ee6d0a7a477e015d6df9e05f11fe673becfefdf6c75ba7f351c5 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"sh","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"PYTHON_PIP_VERSION":"18.1","PYTHON_RELEASE":"3.7.2","PYTHON_VERSION":"3.7.2"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[30,120]}.

Comment: Hi Can anyone help me with the issue.. ?